# Decidability of wildcards in generics in Scala vs Java

Tags: java, scala, generics

I've heard the claim that resolution of Java's wildcards are, in general, undecideable (which was used as a reason by the other person against reification in Java).

1) Does anyone have a definitive reference and/or a proof for this assertion?

Assuming this this is true, then given Scala's declaration-site implementation vs Java's use-site:

2) Does the same proof work for Scala?

3) Are there any run-time implications for Scala because of this?

Comment: you should look up type erasure

Comment: Cruncher: This is inside the source code compiler (i.e. javac) - where else would wildcards be being resolved?

Comment: Could you specifiy what you mean by 'resolution of Java's wildcards'? The only two operations on wildcards I can think of are erasure and containment.

Comment: Generics are purely compiler-side.

Comment: This is an interesting bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6558545?focusedCommentId=13376389&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel

Comment: @lbalazscs That paper is related to contravariance in general. Fwiw, I'm fairly certain that since then scala disallowed declarations for which type checking would diverge.

Comment: Cruncher: Yes - we are discussing the decidability of compiling syntactically legal Java (& Scala) code within the spec of the relevant type system. There are obviously no runtime effects for any language which erases and does not reify its generics (as I believe Scala does, at least partially)